# The profile of gnome-terminal isnt correctly loaded by command line start

Tags: gnome-terminal

I try to start a gnome-terminal by command line.The command line is `"gnome-terminal -e "sh /home/vm/tmp/tmp.sh" --title="tmp test" --tab-with-profile=/home/vm/.bashrc --working-directory=/home/vm/tmp"`.But,There is an error information that Java Environment isn't set.

If I start a gnome-terminal by `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop`,there isn't that error information.

So,I think the profile of gnome-terminal isn't correctly loaded by command line start.

What should I do?

The content of tmp.sh is

```
#!bin/bash;cd /home/vm/tmp/kitchen;./menu
```

Modfied sh to bash dont resolve java Environment isnt set.
Added or deleted `--tab-with-profile='Default'`, don't resolve java Environment isn't set.

If I start a gnome-terminal by `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop`, running sh or `bash /home/vm/tmp/tmp.sh` is normal.

I want to running result by command line as same as by `/usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop`

Answer (score 1):

What exactly are you trying to do?

AFAIK the `--tab-with-profile` is for choosing a predefined **terminal** profile (i.e. one of the sets of application configuration settings from `ls ~/.gconf/apps/gnome-terminal/profiles/`). This is used for setting things like terminal font and color preferences etc. - nothing to do with the **shell** profile or resource file.

If you want to execute a bash script why are you calling it with `sh`? Either just make `/home/vm/tmp/tmp.sh` executable with a `#!/bin/bash` shebang at the top, or execute it via `bash` not `sh` - that way, it should source your `.bashrc` file by default.

If you need to use a non-default bashrc file, you can set that with a `--rcfile` argument to the bash command itself e.g.

```
gnome-terminal -e "bash --rcfile alternatercfile /home/vm/tmp/tmp.sh"
```

Comment: THX.I will try to modify "sh /home/vm/tmp/tmp.sh" to "bash /home/vm/tmp/tmp.sh"

Comment: The content of tmp.sh is "#!bin/bash;cd /home/vm/tmp/kitchen;./menu".

Comment: As @Braiam pointed out, the default gnome-terminal profile should execute your command in a bash shell anyway, so it should be sufficient to do `gnome-terminal -e "/home/vm/tmp/tmp.sh"`

Comment: If ignore bash or sh in command line,the access right will be shown.

Comment: Modfied sh to bash dont resolve java Environment isnt set.If I start a gnome-terminal by /usr/share/applications/gnome-terminal.desktop,running sh or bash /home/vm/tmp/tmp.sh  is normal

Answer (score 0):

`--tab-with-profile` should be used with the name of the profile, not some file path:

> `--tab-with-profile=PROFILENAME`
>                                 Open a tab in the window with the given  profile.  More  than
>                    one of these options can be provided, to open several tabs .

Hence, you should be using the name of the profile in the Profiles window, in this case, I only have the default profile:

```
"gnome-terminal -e "sh /home/vm/tmp/tmp.sh" --title="tmp test" --tab-with-profile='Default' --working-directory=/home/vm/tmp"
```

gnome-terminal automatically loads the `.bashrc` file without being asked (unless you are using another shell) so, there's no need to manually source it. You can also use the `.profile`.

Comment: THX.I had according to your suggestion modified command line.But,The problem is there.The content of tmp.sh is "#!bin/bash;cd /home/vm/tmp/kitchen;./menu"

Comment: Already according to your suggestion  added information